# Android Studio works very slow

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgrade android studio to 3.0.1 and i face problem of Gradle build slow and on run my project it takes extra time and everything is working very slow.Sometimes my system hangs and android studio crashes.Its too pathetic to deal with the problem.
My system Configuration :

Ram : 4gb
Os : Window 7
Processor : Core-i-3 dell vastero

Comment: You need 8GB ram or more if you want to pursue Android Studio.

Comment: I agree with @Enzokie. Your RAM is too low for Android development...

Answer (score 0):

This was a very big problem for me,after many searches on google, i replaced my hard drive and installed Ubuntu to my laptop,now gradle build times are only 2 minutes or less.If you replace your Hard Drive with an SSD,it will reduce the waiting times for gradle and android studio drastically.